# Grep match only before ":"

Tags: grep

Hello How can I grep only match before `:` mark?

If I run `grep test1 file`, it shows all three lines.

```
test1:x:29688:test1,test2
test2:x:22611:test1
test3:x:25163:test1,test3
```

But I would like to get an output `test1:x:29688:test1,test2`

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired lines always start with `test1` then you can do:

```
grep '^test1' file
```

If it's always followed by `:` but not the other (potential) matches then you can include it as part of the pattern:

```
grep 'test1:' file
```

Answer (score 2):

As your data is in row, columns delimited by a character, you may consider `awk`:

```
awk -F: '$1 == "test1"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to add “:” after “test1”, see an example:

```
grep “test1:” file
```

Comment: This answer presently contains "smart quotes". Those don't work in bash -- only `"` is recognized as syntax, not `“` or `”`.

Comment: I’m sorry about the smart quotes, I’m writing on iPhone :D